# Remove a child component from parent dom node in react

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

Unmount components from the same DOM element that mounted them in.

```
ReactDOM.render(<SampleComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Then we would unmount it with:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container'));
```

How to unmount and reattach a component to parent container if container has two or more than two components attached to it e.g.

```
<div id="container">
   <SampleComponent1/>
   <SampleComponent2/>
</div>
```

I want to remove and re-attach the `SampleComponent2` based on some event from `SampleComponent2`.

Comment: `React.renderComponent` is already deprecated, they're using `React.render` now. You also cannot mount two different components on the same container. It will just replace the previous component rendered.

Comment: @Road In new version `0.14.*` need use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`

Comment: you need to store the state and listen to the event. use Flux or Redux library. but flux has some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let React handle component1 and 2 based on props you give it.

For example, with ES6 and a React 0.14 pure component:

```
const App = ({has2}) => 
  <div>
     <Component1 />
     {has2 && <Component2 />}
  </div>
```

If `has2` is truthy, it will show Component2. Simply call render again whenever `has2` changes and React does the rest.